# Write JSON to a file in pretty print format in Django

Tags: json, django, google-bigquery

I need to create some JSON files for exporting data from a Django system to Google Big Query.

The problem is that Google BQ imposes some characteristics in the JSON file, for example, that each object must be in a different line.

json.dumps writes a stringified version of the JSON, so it is not useful for me.

Django serializes writes better JSON, but it put all in one line. All the information I found about pretty-printing is about json.dumps, which I cannot use.

I will like to know if anyone knows a way to create a JSON file in the format required by Big Query.

Example:

```
    JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
    json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
    data_objects = DataObject.objects.all()
    with open("dataobjects.json", "w") as out:
        json_serializer.serialize(data_objects, stream=out)
```

Comment: Can you please share the logic you currently have?

Comment: I added the logic I currently have, @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` is OK. You have to use `indent` like this.

```
import json
myjson = '{"latitude":48.858093,"longitude":2.294694}'
mydata = json.loads(myjson)
print(json.dumps(mydata, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Output:

```
{
    "latitude": 48.858093,
    "longitude": 2.294694
}
```

Comment: That not as the file looks. It print on the screen in pretty format, but the file is stringified, and that format is rejected by BQ